# when does apache camel expression ${} gets substituted with values

Tags: apache-camel

at what point does Apache camel replaces the expression in ${} and replaces it with actual values??

am using spring dsl to write my routes.
eg rout.

```
<from uri="ftp://myUser@host/${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmm}?password=test&delay=60s">
```

Comment: Read the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: Thanks Claus its a good reference. In my case for ftp component GenericFileConsumer->evaluateFileExpression() i was able to figure out the place where it was happening.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to reference the Camel Simple documentation as it is what is actually creating the substitution in this case to generate your date.  In this case the date will be applied everytime a message is sent through your endpoint so the date will be constantly up to date.

http://camel.apache.org/simple.html